# Auto Answer Incoming Calls by Modifying Phone State in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app which needs to auto answer user on incoming call similar to voicemail, but here I want to play a custom audio message. Prior to Android 2.2 this could be done by modifying phone state. Is there a way we can do it in later versions as well?

Comment: _"similar to voice mail, but here I want to play a custom audio message"_. Who do you want to play the message to? The person who made the call, or the person receiving the call? Playing audio to the other party of a voice call is not something you can do from an app on Android.

Comment: Audio message is for the person who made the caller. The feature is similar to custom voicemail. Previously we were able to do this by enabling MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permissions. Is there any other way of doing it now?